# How put a border to a specific container with GestureDetector and multiple containers

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable number of `Container`s created by a button. These `Container`s are wrapped by `GestureDetector` to make them draggable. But I have a problem, because I would like to put a border to the current selected Container.
Here there is what I tried to do:

Here there is the code of the `Container` created:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: yPosition,
      left: xPosition,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (tapInfo) {
          setState(() {
            xPosition += tapInfo.delta.dx;
            yPosition += tapInfo.delta.dy;
            widget.selectedSectionContainer(widget.key, widget.isSelected);

          });
        },
        onTap: () => setState(() {
          widget.selectedSectionContainer(widget.key, widget.isSelected);

        }),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
                color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
                width: 5),
            color: widget.color,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

here the code in the other class where I try to set `isSelected` to the `Container` :

```
selectedSectionContainer: (Key key, bool isSelected) => setState(() {
        
          if (_currentSelectedContainerKey != key) {
            isSelected = true;
            _isSelected = isSelected;
            _currentSelectedContainerKey = key;
            updateSectionContainer(key);
          } else {
            isSelected = false;

            updateSectionContainer(key);
          }
```

by doing so the containers all have the border while instead I would just need to put the border to the selected one

Someone could kindly help me? Thanks

Comment: Flutter tends to bubble the event through out the tree if your containers are overlapping, is this your issue ? Also post more code. Since it is hard to understand what you are doing inside your controller widget.

Comment: here there is the full code of the two classes https://pastebin.com/CNfs5ETG @Nisanth Reddy

Comment: my issue is only to put a border to the  current selected `SectionContainer`, with my code I can get the  `Key` of the selected  `SectionContainer` but then I don't know how to put the border on it

Comment: The code is missing some parts. Are you saying that `widget.isSelected` is always `true` ?

Comment: What parts are missing? Yes is always `true`

Comment: But if `widget.isSelected` is always `true` for all components, then all of them will have the border. Are you saying you are unable to set `widget.isSelected` to `false` ?

Comment: yes I mean this

Comment: Got it. post your `full` code. You have only posted parts of the code and it's not possible to understand what you are doing in other parts of the code. Use https://pastebin.com/ and share the code here

Comment: there are so many parts ... and those parts in my opinion are not significant for what I have to do but that's okay

Comment: here are the other parts https://pastebin.com/jJerak2E, I just put those directly connected to the DashboardScreen class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232685/discussion-between-nico-and-nisanth-reddy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `DashboardScreenState`, you are maintaining only 1 `bool _isSelected` as the state of whether a `Container` is selected or not. But your actual data as to `which` container is selected is present in `_currentSelectedContainerKey`.

So you can't just pass `_isSelected` alone into all your containers, since when one of the is selected and the `_isSelected` is set to `true`, all containers think they are selected.

To avoid this, start passing your `_currentSelectedContainerKey` into your `SectionContainer` along with the `_isSelected`.

So, add this to your `SectionContainer`,

```
final bool isSelected;
final Key currentSelectedContainerKey; // Add this line in the class

required this.isSelected,
required this.currentSelectedContainerKey, // Add this line in constructor
```

Then, pass it into `SectionContainer` while creating them in your `loadSectionContainers` and `addSectionContainer`. (basically wherever you are creating a new `SectionContainer`.

```
isSelected: _isSelected,
currentSelectedContainerKey: _currentSelectedContainerKey // Start passing this
```

Now, finally, change your `border` code to this,

```
border: Border.all(
            color: widget.currentSelectedContainerKey == widget.key && widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
            width: 5),
```

This isn't the `best` approach, but it will solve your issue.
Hope you understood my exaplanation.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! so kind! Why did you say that isn't the best approach?

Comment: Because, we are mainting a `Key` as a state. `Key` is more useful when we want to ontain a widgets state or some other complex property. Here we could've just use some `String` id and it will function just the same. No major problem using keys.

Comment: And glad to have helped :)

Comment: Sorry, just another little thing, if I would like from my `DashboardScreenState` to access the  `xPosition` and the  `yPosition` in `SectionContainerState` how could I do it?

Comment: That depends. When do you want to access them ? Upon some action ? where is that action getting triggered from ?

Comment: When an `ActionButton`  in the `DashboardScreen`  is pressed I would like to access all the `xPosition `and `yPosition` of all the `SectionContainer` present at that moment in the `DashboardScreen`

Comment: For this you need to create `Key`s inside your `DashboardScreen` constructor and then assign them while creating `SectionContainer`, so you will have to store `List<ValueKey>` and when pressed, you can loop over them and use key.currentState to access the state variables that you want

Comment: but I actually already assign a `Key` to each `SectionContainer` ... so I just need to add them to a list and loop them anymore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232686/discussion-between-nico-and-nisanth-reddy).

Comment: yes, you are directly creating them while assigning, so create first, then read through your list and assign

Comment: Could you kindly give me a little example of code via https://pastebin.com/? because I can't understand